# C# Why does this code not show a GUI properly?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

```
class Program
{
    static String ChannelName = null;
    static Form1 f;

    static void Main()
    {
        f = new Form1();
        f.Show();
        try
        {
            MY CODE WHICH CALLS INTO ANOTHER CLASS BUT CANNOT PASS THE GUI INSTANCE AS
            IT USES REMOTING
        }
    }
}
```

**I know this isnt the best/normal way to do it, but i need to write data to the GUI from a class which has bo instance of the GUI so i was going to call Program.method() and use a function to write to the GUI in program**. However when i run the above my GUI displays but with the windows hourglass?

Could someone show me a quick fix so that i can still crudely show the GUI, let the application code run and then later write to the GUI?

Comment: First: I assume Windows Forms due to the new Form1(); instantiation. Am I wrong? Second: what is it you're trying to do, what is your goal out of the code? What do you wish to achieve?

Comment: Hit the control + break buttons to break into your code while the hourglass shows. I think that will highlight where your problem area is.

Comment: I've got an interface class which receives data about the registry. I want to write this data to the GUI. The problem is im using hooking and there's no place where i can put the GUI declaration and it only get called once, as the rest of the code happens each time an action is seen.

So i want to declare the GUI before the registy monitoring begins and then in the registry data Program.Form1.ListBox.items.insert(0,String)..... 

but i get this hourglass problem displaying the GUI

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the [`Form.ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) method.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        f = new Form1();

        try
        {
            f.label1.Text = "Changed Label from Console!";
            f.textBox1.Text = "Changed Textbox from Console!";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        f.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Should make it work.

Comment: Hey, ok the GUI works fine (THANK YOU!!) but it would appear my CODE after it is now not executing, asif the GUI acts like a while loop?

Comment: Yes, because the code in the try-catch will be executed only after closing the modal Form (that's what you get by calling ShowDialog method) ...

Comment: Just put the try clause before the ShowDialog() method. (Updated Answer)

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys i did it in the end! I put my GUI creation into a thread and gave my gui class a methodinvoker which allows me to use a delegate to write to it from another thread.

My data class calls a method in program, which sends the string to write to the methodinvoker in the gui and wala!

Thanks for your ideas and help!

Answer (score 0):

You could move your try block to the [Form.Shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=VS.100).aspx) event to allow your form to be shown before it begins processing.